# Accessing file share from ETL package in SQL Always-On configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, azure-vm

How can I access the file share from **ETL**?

Here are my environment details:

- I have 2 nodes in a windows **cluster**. node **01** and node **02**
- **SQL Server 2014** is installed on both the nodes.
- Both are **Windows Server 2012 R2** machines
- I have **file share** created in **Azure** portal and mapped as **G**: in both the nodes (**01 and 02**)

My ETL package is using C# code. It wants to read and write files on one shared folder for processing. I want it to use shared drive G.

**Problem Statement:** One of the nodes can be down at any time, so I cannot hard code as below:

```
//node01/G
```

Can I use file share feature (role) in a failover cluster? if yes, where will that new drive be stored?

I saw the post [Accessing an Azure Storage Account File Share from an ASP.NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759421/accessing-an-azure-storage-account-file-share-from-an-asp-net-application) on Stack Overflow, but that requires code changes in all the ETL packages. Is that is the only way?

Comment: [Considered using DFS?](http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/high-available-file-share-in-windows-azure-using-dfs/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are suggesting that you require a highly available file share (see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/clausjor/2012/06/07/smb-transparent-failover-making-file-shares-continuously-available/). In order to do this you will obviously need Clustered storage (an ip and network name). It would be a little unusual to do this using your Availability Group's Windows Cluster since really that is only in place to provide Quorum and meta-data synchronisation/ mediation of AG Cluster HA objects -and I would personally advice against complicating that deployment -Clusters should be kept as simple and easy to troubleshoot as possible. Instead I would advise to use a remote fileshare - which you can either make highly available via another windows cluster or just use a standalone server (depending upon requirements).